# Javascript selecting links within divs with IDs that begin with "myText"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, selector

I have this right now, which selects the whole div:

```
    $('div[id^="myText"]').click(function () {
```

And I want it to select only the links within that. I tried:

```
    $('div[id^="myText"] a').click(function () {
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the html markup? Do the links exist when you call it?

Comment: yes the links are written in with a script before this.

Answer (score 1):

If the links are "written in with a script", I'm guessing they are dynamic, so :

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="myText"] a', function () {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: it works in jsfiddle, but not on my actual site. any reason for this?

Comment: @DerekThomasTran - You remembered the document ready function, and are using jQuery version 1.7 at least (it's at 2.0 now), right? And the div with an ID that starts with `myText***` is not dynamic, is it !

Comment: The divs are dynamically populated from a SQL database. But then I'm adding a link to each div using javascript. In JSfiddle, the divs are static for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @DerekThomasTran - I changed the answer slightly, try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('div[id^="myText"]').find('a').click(...
```

or

```
$('a','div[id^="myText"]').click(...
```